# How to determine every 100 item in a while loop php?

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently learning PHP, and I'm struggling with this:

"For every 100 ordered products in a category, 2% will be deducted:"

This is my code:

```php
$gesA = 309; // (The amount of product)
                
$gesN = 1011.08; // (The full price of product)
                
$i = 1;
                
while($i) 
{
    if($gesA % 100 == 0)
    {
        echo $gesN;
        echo "<br>";
        $gesN = $gesN / 0.2;
    }
    
    $i++;
    $gesN++;
}

echo $gesN;
```

Yet, I can't figure it out. Could someone help me?

Comment: you need to terminate the loop eventually, use your `$gesA` as your stopper. so continue to loop while `$i` is still less than `$genA`, then check if `$i` modulo `100` is equal to zero. that's it. i don't think you need to increment `$gesN` every iteration too.

Comment: This could be severely simplified. I just gotta ask to make sure I understand the requirements correctly - every 100 products adds a 2% discount cumulatively, meaning that 309 items should yield 6% discount? Or is there a more complicated calculation in mind?

Comment: And, I have to say, you really must brush up on your math. You try to calculate a 2% discount by dividing by `0.2`. Makes absolutely no sense as you're actually *increasing* the value and because `0.2` is 20%, not 2%.

Answer (score 0):

First you find how many times it is that there are 100 ordered products, which can be calculated by divide the number of products by 100.

```
$no = $getA / 100;
```

But that can get you a floating number so you remove the decimal part with `floor()`

```
$no = floor($getA / 100);
```

Then the percentage will be 2% times the integer number.

```
$deductPercentage = 2 * $no;
```

And the final product price will be the remaining of the deducted price

```
$deductedPrice = $gesN * $deductPercentage / 100;
$finalPrice = $gesN - $deductedPrice;
```